# Alignment of integer types

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I know that the size and alignment of structures aren't always the same but is there any guarantees for the size and alignment of the integer types? For example, is the size and alignment of an `int` always the same or could they be different?

To demonstrate my question, will this assertion never fail?

```
int main() {
    assert(_Alignof(int) == sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the sizes of `int` etc are the same across platforms, so there can't be any guarantee that their alignments will be the same.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with that, it may be relevant to note that `_Alignof` may not be an effective predictor of `stddef.h`'s `offsetof`.  (That is, for a struct, you can't necessarily just add up the alignments and sizes of the prior members to find a given member's offset.)

Comment: Why do you think at all there is/has to be a correlation between the size and alignment of any type?

Comment: On my platform, the alignment and size of integer types are the same. I wasn't sure if this was guaranteed or not on other platforms so I asked a question and learned a little more about alignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alignment and size of integer types can be different. For example on [GCC x86 32-bit](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rM69EITcxM09DU6Gai7OgCMhP01BSrSpVAOKYPCUdhXjHnMz0vPw0jZz8vHQFEKGpo1CcWZWKIqRpzVX7//@/5LScxPTi/7q5xkYA):

```
_Alignof(long long) == 4
  sizeof(long long) == 8
```

Comment: Is this because the `long long` data type in this architecture is 64-bits and made of 2 32-bit words?

Comment: @CameronWhite Yes, exactly.

Comment: It can not  be one word on 32 bit system